# Erro resolver handler JavaFX metodo dentro classeDAO e controler com banco MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Estou tentando cria um simples sistema de caixa (entradas dinheiro menos saídas dinheiro igual saldo). E fiz um método na classe *DespesaDAO* que vai no banco com a consulta personalizada:

```
(SELEC SUM(VALOR) FROM DESPESA WHERE VALOR IS NOT NULL AND DATA='USUARIO ESCOLHE')
```

Na classe DespesaDAO esta assim:

```
public Despesa somarValoresDespesa(Despesa despesa, LocalDate data){
    String sql = "SELECT SUM(valor) FROM despesa WHERE valor IS NOT NULL AND data=?";
    //double soma = 0.0;
    Despesa retorno = new Despesa();
    data = despesa.getData();
    try{
        PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(data));//Estava "Date.valueOf(data)"
        ResultSet resultado = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (resultado.next()){
           double soma = resultado.getDouble(1);
           despesa.setValor(soma);
           retorno = despesa;
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(DespesaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

E no controller assim:

```
@FXML
public void somaVlrDespesa(Despesa despesa, LocalDate data) throws IOException {
    //Despesa despesa = new Despesa();
    //LocalDate data;
    data = dtData.getValue();
    if(despesa != null && data != null){
        despesa = despesaDAO.somarValoresDespesa(despesa, data);
        txValorTotalDespesas.setText(String.valueOf(despesa.getValor()));
        System.out.println(despesa);
    } else {
        dtData.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        txValorTotalDespesas.setText(" ");
    }
}
```

Na *view* desse *controller* tem um botão e uma caixa de texto. Então o usuário escolhe a data e clica no botão e o método faz a consulta e DEVERIA setar na caixa o valor trazido do banco. DEVERIA. Mas esta dando essa exceção:

```
   Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#somaVlrDespesa',
either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
file:/D:/Caxa-Renova/cxren/dist/run1293869844/cxren.jar!/cxren/view/FXMLAnchorPaneCadastroDespesa.fxml:54
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at cxren.controller.FXMLVBoxPrincipalController.eventoBotaoAbrirCadastroDespesa(FXMLVBoxPrincipalController.java:38)
    ... 58 more
```

Diz que não acha o método `#somaVlrDespesa`. Mas o FXML esta salvo correto e se eu colocar no lugar algo para sair (System.exit(0)) não dá erro.

O que pode ser?

Se precisar das classes todas, eu envio.

ATUALIZANDO segue o FXML desse controller

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="ancorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cxren.controller.FXMLAnchorPaneCadastroDespesaController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.7587646076794657" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="104.0" prefHeight="484.0" prefWidth="1200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="548.0" prefWidth="432.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tbCadastroDespesa" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="906.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tbColunaData" prefWidth="91.0" text="DATA" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="tbColunaNome" prefWidth="123.0" text="NOME" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="tbColunaValor" prefWidth="109.0" text="VALOR" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="tbColunaDescrição" prefWidth="581.0" text="DESCRIÇÃO" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="514.0">
               <children>
                  <DatePicker fx:id="dtData" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="49.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
                  <ComboBox fx:id="cbNome" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="117.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" promptText="Escolha o Tipo..." />
                  <TextField fx:id="txValor" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="201.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
                  <TextField fx:id="txDescrição" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="319.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
                  <Button fx:id="btCadInserir" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="439.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="INSERIR" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" />
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="53.0" text="DATA" />
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="121.0" text="NOME" />
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="204.0" text="VALOR" />
                  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="323.0" text="DESCRIÇÃO" />
                  <Button fx:id="btCadDespesaVoltar" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="509.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#eventoBotaoVoltarInicio2" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="53.0" text="&lt;--" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="513.0" text="Voltar ao Inicio">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Italic" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="CADASTRO DE ITENS DE DESPESA - CAIXA RENOVA" textFill="#5341ab">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="811.0" layoutY="19.0" text="TOTAL DAS DESPESAS:" />
      <TextField fx:id="txValorTotalDespesas" layoutX="940.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btCarregaValor" layoutX="496.0" layoutY="15.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#somaVlrDespesa" text="MOSTRA TOTAL DE DESPESAS POR DATA" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Obrigado.
COLOCANDO IMPORTS SOLICITADO

```
mport cxren.model.dao.DespesaDAO;
import cxren.model.database.BancoDeDados;
import cxren.model.database.DatabaseFactory;
import cxren.model.domain.Despesa;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
```

Comment: Posta o fxml que utiliza esse *controller*.

Comment: **renan** editei a pegunta e coloquei o FXML. Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia incluir também os imports da classe `FXMLAnchorPaneCadastroDespesaController`? Até o momento parece tudo ok no seu código.

Comment: **renan** esta la os imports. Valeu.